# AngularJS ui-grid does not filter date

Tags: angularjs, date, angular-ui-grid

I'm trying to get UI-Grid on my Angular App to filter dates properly but it doesn't seem to respond to any kind of filter change. I've tried going over the docs and using their example:

```
displayName: "Long Date", cellFilter: 'date:"longDate"', filterCellFiltered:true,
```

But nothing seems to change the format of the date, here is my code currently: (updated)

```
$scope.gridOptionsClaims = {
enableSorting: true,
enableFiltering: true,
showColumnFooter: true,
enableGridMenu: true,
columnDefs: [
{ field: 'date', name: 'Date', displayName: "Date", type: 'date', cellFilter: 'date:"MM-dd-yyyy"', filterCellFiltered: true },
{ field: 'transaction_id', name: 'Purchase Order', displayName: "Purchase Order" },
{ field: 'full_name', name: 'Salesperson', displayName: "Salesperson" }
            ]};
```

I've tried using filters 'date:MM-dd-yyy' and that didn't work either. Could anyone please tell me what I'm missing?

Comment: You should filter them as dates first in your controller somethiing like: *item.date = $filter('date')(item.date, "dd/MM/yyyy");*

Answer (score 0):

Did you enable filtering with `enableFiltering: true` property?
Also, try to define cellFilter with filters as you already mentioned:

```
cellFilter: 'date:"yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm"'
```

Comment: Hi Corry, yes I do have enableFiltering: true turned on for this grid. I updated my code in the original questions to include more information. Thank you for the help!

Comment: Did you try to initialize your grid options as `$scope.gridOptions = {...}` ?